# value of calendar_date_select to controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, calendar

i will pass the value generated by this calendar_date_select to the controller. onchange code needs modification to do so. any suggestions?

```
<%= calendar_date_select_tag "meeting_date_1", @time, 
    :embedded => true, 
    :time => true, 
    :minute_interval => 15, 
    :onchange => "$('dv').update($F(this));" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! This works! The controller:

```
@team.meeting_date_1 = params[:mtg_date]
```

The view:

```
<%= calendar_date_select_tag "calendar", @time, 
    :embedded => true, 
    :time => true, 
    :minute_interval => 15,
    :onchange => remote_function(
        :method => :put,
        :url => {:action => "update_team_mtg_date", :id => @team.id}, 
        :with => "'mtg_date='+($F(this))",
        :loading => "$('date_spinner').setStyle({visibility: 'visible'});",
        :complete => "$('date_spinner').setStyle({visibility: 'hidden'});" ) %>
```